# How to design AsyncTasks for networked Android apps

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I start to build an app that some activities will fetch&post data from a server. E.g., a login activity will post username and password to try to login, a list activity will load items from server database. Now for each communication between server and app, I use one `AsyncTask` to do it. For reuse purposes, I have a base `MyAsyncTask` class and each real task extends it.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    protected String path;

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, String path){
        this.path=path;//each task will connect to its own url path
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String ret=null;
        try {
            ret=postData(params);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public String postData(String... params) throws IOException{
        String httpUrl=Constants.SERVER_URL+path;
        HttpPost httpRequest=new HttpPost(httpUrl);
        List<NameValuePair> httpparams=formHttpParams(params);  
        //create HttpClient and connect to server and post data 
        ... ...
    }   

    public ArrayList<NameValuePair> formHttpParams(String params[]){
        return new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();//sub classes need to override the parameter assignment
    }
    //protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}//override this for response handling
}
```

**My question is that can I use a single `AsyncTask` to do this? Otherwise, I will have a lot of sub classes extending `MyAsyncTask`.** Is it the proper way to deal with Android networking apps? (Currently, if I want to do a single class, I will have complicated parameter parsing processes and manage multiple corresponding paths.)

Also, if I still use multiple sub classes to extend this base class, will there be a single "session" between my app and the server, so I can save user identity information (like username) in server's session part? (This is a "side" question as I can experiment with this of course...)

Comment: Check out Volley.. and there are many others like it. Don't re-invent the wheel, especially if you've never built a car before.

Comment: Nice to know an official solution Volley. It should be the inherent component together with AsyncTask... PS, curse those downvoters, hah...

Comment: Android-Query is an option and seems easier to use for people from Web and pure Java, like me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) REST client from Square. The main problem with AsyncTask that you can't handle orientation changes easily, but if you want use it you can pass [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in AsyncTask constructor.

```
public interface Command {
    public Object execute();
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Object> {

    private Exception e;

    private Command command;

    public MyTask(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public Object doInBackground() {
        try {
            return command.execute();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            this.e = e;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(final Object result) {
       //Handle your result
    }
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that same problem a long time ago. Since then I implemented my own classes to post/get JSON data from a server. I use an interface to callback into activities or fragments when I make the call, that way I just have to customize the callback, and not the whole Asynctask. Something like:

```
/**
 * An interface for calling back from service
 * 
 * @author
 *
 */
public interface JSONCallback {
    public void onError(String error);
    /**
     * A JSONObject or a JSONArray
     * @param object
     */
    public void onSuccess(Object object);
}


public static class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer>{

    Activity activity;
    String message;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Object object = null;
    HttpEntity entity;
    JSONCallback callback;
    boolean getJSONArray;
    private String error = null;
    private HashMap<String, String> headers;

    public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public void setHeaders(HashMap<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public PostTask(Activity activity, String message, HttpEntity entity, JSONCallback callback){
        this.activity  = activity;
        this.message = message;
        this.entity = entity;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.getJSONArray = false;
    }

    public PostTask(Activity activity, String message, HttpEntity entity, JSONCallback callback, boolean getJSONArray){
        this.activity  = activity;
        this.message = message;
        this.entity = entity;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.getJSONArray = getJSONArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        if(message != null){
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, null, message, true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    cancel(true); //cancel this task
                }
            });
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            object = getJSONPOST(activity, params[0], entity, getJSONArray, headers);
            return 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if(callback!=null && !activity.isFinishing()){
            if(result == 0){
                callback.onSuccess(object);
            }else{
                callback.onError(error);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Object getJSONPOST(Context context, String url, HttpEntity entity, boolean isJSONArray, HashMap<String, String> headers) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try{
        client.getCookieStore().clear();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(entity);
//      post.setHeader( "content-type", "application/json" );
//      post.setHeader( "charset", "UTF-8" );
    if(headers != null){
        Set<String> keys = headers.keySet();
        for(String key:keys){
//              Log.d("", "Header name: "+key+", header value: "+headers.get(key));
            post.setHeader(key, headers.get(key));
        }
    }
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

//      Log.d("", "Response error code: "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        if(!isJSONArray)
            return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        else
            return new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    }

Notice that this model is just for explanation, and should be used to create your own, so you it can fit your needs. I've done this for GET, PUT and DELETE methods.

Side Question: You can get the CookieManager from the HttpClient (if you use cookies to keep the session) and store them in a global member, or persist them even if the app closes. It all depend on what you're doing.

Hope it helps.